# Different 2D convolution results between keras and scipy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scipy, convolution

I found some results difficult to understand when trying to debug my neural network. I tried to do some computations offline using `scipy` (1.3.0), and I am not having the same results as with `keras` (2.3.1) with a `tensorflow` (1.14.0) backend. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

image = np.array([[-1.16551484e-04, -1.88735046e-03, -7.90571701e-03,
        -1.52302440e-02, -1.55315138e-02, -8.40757508e-03,
        -2.12123734e-03, -1.49851941e-04],
       [-1.88735046e-03, -3.05623915e-02, -1.28019482e-01,
        -2.46627569e-01, -2.51506150e-01, -1.36146188e-01,
        -3.43497843e-02, -2.42659380e-03],
       [-7.90571701e-03, -1.28019482e-01, -5.06409585e-01,
        -6.69258237e-01, -6.63918257e-01, -5.31925797e-01,
        -1.43884048e-01, -1.01644937e-02],
       [-1.52302440e-02, -2.46627569e-01, -6.69258296e-01,
         2.44587708e+00,  2.72079444e+00, -6.30891442e-01,
        -2.77190477e-01, -1.95817426e-02],
       [-1.55315138e-02, -2.51506120e-01, -6.63918316e-01,
         2.72079420e+00,  3.01719952e+00, -6.19484246e-01,
        -2.82673597e-01, -1.99690927e-02],
       [-8.40757508e-03, -1.36146188e-01, -5.31925797e-01,
        -6.30891442e-01, -6.19484186e-01, -5.57167232e-01,
        -1.53017864e-01, -1.08097391e-02],
       [-2.12123734e-03, -3.43497805e-02, -1.43884048e-01,
        -2.77190447e-01, -2.82673597e-01, -1.53017864e-01,
        -3.86065207e-02, -2.72730505e-03],
       [-1.49851941e-04, -2.42659380e-03, -1.01644937e-02,
        -1.95817426e-02, -1.99690927e-02, -1.08097391e-02,
        -2.72730505e-03, -1.92666746e-04]], dtype='float32')

kernel = np.array([[ 0.04277903 ,  0.5318366  ,  0.025291916],
       [ 0.5756132  , -0.493123   ,  0.116359994],
       [ 0.10616145 , -0.319581   , -0.115053006]], dtype='float32')

print('Mean of original image', np.mean(image))

## Scipy result

res_scipy = convolve2d(image, kernel.T, mode='same')

print('Mean of convolution with scipy', np.mean(res_scipy))

## Keras result

def init(shape, dtype=None):
    return kernel[..., None, None]
im = Input((None, None, 1))
im_conv = Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=init)(im)
model = Model(im, im_conv)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

res_keras = model.predict_on_batch(image[None, ..., None])

print('Mean of convolution with keras', np.mean(res_keras))
```

When visualizing the results, I found that they are actually symmetric (point symmetry around the center modulo a little shift).
[image: on the left the <code>scipy</code> result, on the right the <code>keras</code> result, both with the same scale].

I tried something empirical like transposing the kernel, but it didn't change anything.

---

EDIT
Thanks to @kaya3 comment, I realized that rotating the kernel by 180 degrees did the trick. However, I still don't understand why I need to do this to get the same results.

Comment: Since the difference is a 180-degree rotation, did you consider rotating the kernel 180 degrees (instead of taking the transpose)?

Comment: well I hadn't thought of that and it turns out it exactly reconciles the 2 versions. Now why do I have to do this to get the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is usually called convolution in neural networks (and image processing) is not exactly the mathematical concept of [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), which is what [`convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) implements, but the similar one of [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation), which is implemented by [`correlate2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html):

```
res_scipy = correlate2d(image, kernel.T, mode='same')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for certain without reading the source code for these two libraries, but there is more than one straightforward way to write a convolution algorithm, and evidently these two libraries implement it in different ways.

One way is to "paint" the kernel onto the output, for each pixel of the image:

```py
from itertools import product

def convolve_paint(img, ker):
    img_w, img_h = len(img[0]), len(img)
    ker_w, ker_h = len(ker[0]), len(ker)
    out_w, out_h = img_w + ker_w - 1, img_h + ker_h - 1
    out = [[0]*out_w for i in range(out_h)]
    for x,y in product(range(img_w), range(img_h)):
        for dx,dy in product(range(ker_w), range(ker_h)):
            out[y+dy][x+dx] += img[y][x] * ker[dy][dx]
    return out
```

Another way is to "sum" the contributing amounts at each pixel in the output:

```py
def convolve_sum(img, ker):
    img_w, img_h = len(img[0]), len(img)
    ker_w, ker_h = len(ker[0]), len(ker)
    out_w, out_h = img_w + ker_w - 1, img_h + ker_h - 1
    out = [[0]*out_w for i in range(out_h)]
    for x,y in product(range(out_w), range(out_h)):
        for dx,dy in product(range(ker_w), range(ker_h)):
            if 0 <= y-dy < img_h and 0 <= x-dx < img_w:
                out[y][x] += img[y-dy][x-dx] * ker[dy][dx]
    return out
```

These two functions produce the same output. However, notice that the second one has `y-dy` and `x-dx` instead of `y+dy` and `x+dx`. If the second algorithm is written with `+` instead of `-`, as might seem natural, then the results will be as if the kernel is rotated by 180 degrees, which is as you've observed.

It's unlikely that either library uses such a simple algorithm to do convolution. For larger images and kernels it's more efficient to use a Fourier transform, applying the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). But the difference between the two libraries is likely to be caused by something similar to this.